# Can't create Azure VMs from an uploaded Windows 8 VHD

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

It appears I'm able to successfully upload my sysprep'd, RDP enabled, fixed size Windows 8 VHD to my Azure environment using the following Powershell line:

```
add-azurevhd -destination "https://atoqa.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/zTemplate-W8sp.vhd" -localfilepath "C:\VM\W8_Template\W8-Sysprep.vhd"
```

I am using the Azure interface to create an image from that uploaded VHD.  However, my problem starts when I attempt to create a VM from that image.  On the Virtual Machine Instances page the new VM is listed as Running (Provisioning) but never seems to come out of that provisioning state.

On a related note, I've successfully uploaded a VHD identical to the one described above except it isn't sysprep'd.  I can successfully create a disk from the VHD and seemingly can create a VM using that disk with no issue.  However, I can't RDP into the box (using the file provided by Azure).  I thought something might be blocked on my end, but I've had no issues RDP'ing to the servers I've created using the images provided by Microsoft.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  I know I haven't provided all of the minute details of what I'm doing, but if you want them I can certainly post them here.  Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client Operating systems (like Windows 8) are not Supported in windows Azure Virtual Machines. Only Windows Server based images are supported (and some flavors of Linux).

Comment: Actually, I just managed to get a Windows XP VM to run on Azure. It's slow but it works.

Comment: @Remy could you please detail how did you get this VM on Azure? I would like to build one there.

Comment: Nothing will stop you from experimenting. You can upload any VHD with any OS on Windows Azure and try to boot it. However there are only a few operating systems that are **supported**. And **supported** means that if something goes wrong, you can call support and they **have to** investigate. While you can still run any OS, but if it is not in the list of **supported** ones, you just risk playing with it and nothing more - i.e. no production use.

Comment: Bascially I created a VM normally with V-Server locally. Don't remember all the exact steps, but there are tutorial out there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering just to offer you an alternative, but I've not tested any of these.

The first is for uploading pure Win7/8 VMs on Azure, and one of the disclaimers is to previously enable your RDP on the VM, and I would also add another step that is to remember the creation of endpoints on Azure.

http://jeffchiu.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/kb-how-to-create-a-windows-7-azure-vm-image/

The other is to make a Win2012 server capable of running Win8 Projects.

http://mythoughtsonit.com/2013/05/build-a-windows-8-developer-environment-in-the-cloud/